# Что означает эта строка в php коде? Просто работаю с Joomshopping

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

```
<th class="jshop_img_description_center" width="20%">
    <?php print _JSHOP_IMAGE ?>
</th>
```

Вот такой вот код.. почитал про print в php, но не понял, что за момент с _JSHOP_IMAGE? Это типо переменная, в которой хранится картинка ( или например слово "Наименование", если поставить туда _JSHOP_ITEM )
Что это? В dreamweaver искал во всех файлах такую строку, но нигде не нашел ее значения

Можете объяснить?)

Comment: Не думал что кто ещё пользуется этим редактором. _JSHOP_IMAGE это константа, туда что угодно положить могли

Comment: Окей, но я прошелся по всем файлам и нигде такой строки "_JSHOP_IMAGE" не нашел что-то.. ( там есть функция, чтобы вписать строку и поискать во всех файлах )..
Где ее могли определить тогда? Как в нее что-то положили?

Comment: Потому что и нужен нормальный редактор чтоб можно было кликнуть на константу и перейти к определению. если принт срабатывает - значит плохо искали, если нет - будет ошибка. Гугл говорит что это константа с JoomShopping, так что они там в конфиге где-то лежать должны

Comment: А какой редактор посоветуете?) Чтобы можно было подключиться к файлам сайта на сервере ( ftp )

Comment: Я PhpStorm использую, там есть и ftp, и sftp, и ssh, и много чего ещё